# Getting auth sign message when connecting cloud server using opencpu

Tags: r, linux, curl, terminal, opencpu

I am trying to expose a sample r model as API so I created R package. In my local machine , I am able to get the output using the command :

```
curl http://local host/5656/ocpu/library/mypackage/R/tv/json -F "input=@test.csv"
```

But when I am trying the same in my AWS linux cloud server on CentOS , I am not getting the output. I tried the command :

```
curl 13.228.109.233:8787/p/5656/ocpu/library/mypackage/R/tv/json -F "input=@test.csv"
```

and I get the output as

```
http:&#x2F;&#x2F;13.228.109.233:8787&#x2F;auth-sign-in?appUr‌​i=%2Fp%2F5656%2Focpu‌​%2Flibrary%2Fmypacka‌​ge%2FR%2Ftv%2Fjson .
```

The R package is loaded into the my R studio server and I am trying to access it using putty. I installed the open cpu using the command :

```
yum install opencpu-server
```

It looks like it is asking for some authentication but I am not able to get what it means. Am I missing something here? 
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If one visits the URL with a browser, one sees the RStudio-Server login screen. And indeed, you are connecting to port 8787, which is the default port for Rstudio Server. Try URLs below http://13.228.109.233/ocpu/ instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Ralf suggests, that was the error , I was giving the wrong URL . Also, whenever we install opencpu in CentOS , just doing a 'yum install opencpu-server' might not be sufficient. We need to execute the entire built script:  https://github.com/opencpu/opencpu-server/blob/master/rpm/buildscript.sh

Without executing the build script , I was not able to connect to opencpu server.
Just in case someone gets the same issue.